# On Langrange Multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I don’t understand why in the Lagrange multiplier formula the constraint has to have a gradient too.
$\nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n)= \lambda \nabla g (x_1, \dots, x_n)$

Isn’t $g(x_1, \dots, x_n)=0 $ just a curve?

Comment: Usually, mathmaticians don't ask questions like _why_ something is true, but rather if it's true, how can I proove it, and how can I use it to proove other things.

Comment: I wold strongly disagree with Eminem. Mathematics *is* about understanding *why* some things are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that even $g\left(x_1,\dots,x_n\right)=0$ that doesn't mean that  $\nabla g\left(x_1,\dots,x_n\right)=0$.

$\nabla g$ is a vector, and with parametar $\lambda$ we can check when this vector is proportional to the vector $\nabla f$. If you remember that $\nabla f$ represent direction in which function $f$ grows, then proportionality of $\nabla g$ and $\nabla f$ tell us that curve $g=0$ is tangent to the levels of $f$ and that means that we have the stationary point of $f$ on the curve $g=0$.

Reading Wikipedia page on [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Single_constraint) should give you more motivation for the $\lambda$.